# What is the composition, function, and classification of “6-Thio-2-Deoxyguanosine” and “13-mer thio-phosphoramidate”? How do I learn more about them?

Tags: biochemistry, oxidation-state, chemical-biology, drugs, dna-rna

I am assigned the task of explaining a biomedical research paper, it is about telomere and telomerase , and it talks a lot about the molecule Thio-2-Deoxyguanosine , 13-mer thio-phosphoramidate and " 6-thio-2-deoxyguanosine 5′-triphosphate".

I have a good understanding of what the paper is saying , but I would really like to know as much as I can about those molecules, their chemical classification and biological function and chemical composition, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

(Please do not mark this as off-topic , as I asked this in biochemistry stack exchange, and they wanted me to put it here )

Comment: Google is your friend! 6-thio-2'-deoxyguanosine for example is commercially available  https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/sml1296?lang=en&region=GB

Comment: "How do I learn more about them ?". Go to Chemspider, Pubchem, ChEMBL, and literally all the databases which can be found under the "Identifiers" section of Wikipedia for that specific molecule. The 3 databases mentioned above give a summary of molecules, their physical and chemical attributes as well as a link to further readings/papers. You can also find more information about your molecules in the references of your first paper. http://www.chemspider.com/     https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/     https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/    good luck!

Comment: we all know those sites, zero results in all databases